# Perpendicular Distance between PAPI and Aiming point

Tags: runways, airport-markings, papi

We are in the middle of a new runway construction. The airport requested the aiming point to follow the PAPI. Should they be aligned head to head, or there can be some meters difference?

Comment: Hi shirley, is there a reason not to install them such that they are aligned?

Comment: Based on the airport preference, it is required to have the aiming point following the PAPI location. So, should it be head by head or it can be only coincide? @Jpe61

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean by head by head / coincide.